# Is there a way to have a single static variable for a template class (for all types) without breaking encapsulation

Tags: c++, templates, static

I need a way to have a single static variable for all kinds of types of my template class

`template <class T> class Foo { static Bar foobar;};`

Well, the line above will generate a Bar object named foobar for every type `T`, but this is not what i want, i basically want a way to declare a variable of type Bar, so every object of type `Foo` has access to the same `foobar` variable, independent of `T`.

I tried to use another class to store the private stuff, but that doesnt work, because the standard does not allow stuff like `template <class T> friend class Foo<T>;`

So the obvious solution (shown below) is to have a global variable `Bar foobar`, but this obviously violates the information hiding concept (of proper encapsulation):

```
Bar Foo_DO_NOT_TOUCH_THIS_PLEASE_foobar;
template <class T> class Foo { static Bar& foobar;};
template <class T> Bar& Foo<T>::foobar=Foo_DO_NOT_TOUCH_THIS_PLEASE_foobar;
```

Ofcourse you can additionally use a detail namespace (thats what i am currently doing), but is there another way which really prohibits users from messing around with your private static variables ?

Additonally this solution will get quite messy when you have to declare lots of static methods in a similar fashion, because you will most likely have to extensivly use the friend keyword like `friend RetType Foo_detail::StaticFunc(ArgT1, ArgT2)`.

And the users wont have a nice interface since they cant use those functions like they are used to `Foo<T>::someFunc()` but instead they will have to call something like `Foo_static::someFunc()` (if you use the namespace `Foo_static` for public static functions).

So is there any other solution which does not break encapsulation, and/or does not introduce lots of syntax overhead ?

EDIT: 
based on all your anwsers, i tried following, and it works as intended:

```
typedef int Bar;
template <class T> class Foo;

class FooBase
{
    static Bar foobar;
    public:
        template <class T> friend class Foo;
};
Bar FooBase::foobar;

template <class T> class Foo : public FooBase
{
    public:
    using FooBase::foobar;
};
```

this solution has the benefit, that users can not inherit from FooBase.

Comment: You can declare an unrelated class a friend, just not with that syntax. Check the answer by @rmn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps inherit the static member?

```
class OneBarForAll
{
protected:
  static Bar foobar;
};

template <class T>
class Foo : public OneBarForAll
{

};
```

Lots of `Foo<T>`'s will be made, but only one `OneBarForAll`.

One potential problem with this is that there's nothing stopping other users of the code from inheriting from `OneBarForAll` and modifying `foobar` anyway.

Ideally you do want the template friend, as that best describes the access requirements of your design, but C++ does not currently allow that.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for

```
template <class T> friend class Foo<T>;
```

is

```
template <class T> friend class Foo;
```

(which means that every instantiation of Foo is a friend of the class you define it in)

So perhaps you can go with the solution you ruled out before.

Comment: i used this in my solution aswell, see my question

Answer (score 3):

you could do:

```
struct Base {
  static Foo foo;
};
//init foo here

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base {
...
};
...
Derived<Bar>::foo;
```

It works in g++

Answer (score 1):

Why not inherit from a non-template base class?